# Matching url with array list of words in AngularJS ui-router

Tags: regex, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using AngularJS + ui-router, I need to match a url with list of words:

However, using a regex I have tried using one or 2 words and it worked

```
 url: '/{source:(?:John|Paul)}/:id'
```

But i need to match my url with an list of words.

example:
var sourceList= ['John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo'];
url: '/{source:(?:sourceList)}/:id'

is there way to compare my url with matching list of array??

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not fully sure what exactly you are searching for... because it could be a dynamic url matcher or just smart regex. Here is a [plunker with working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/MdazdvpVKjZhNjI6ErAH?p=preview). It in fact 1) only builds the regex from the passed list of names... 2) shows `urlMatcher` in action

The answer here would be: use the `UrlMatcher`.

#### [$urlMatcherFactory and UrlMatchers](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#urlmatcherfactory-and-urlmatchers)

> Defines the syntax for url patterns and parameter placeholders. This factory service is used behind the scenes by $urlRouterProvider to cache compiled UrlMatcher objects, instead of having to re-parse url patterns on every location change. Most users will not need to use $urlMatcherFactory directly, however it could be useful to craft a UrlMatcher object and pass it as the url to the state config.

Example:

```
var urlMatcher = $urlMatcherFactory.compile("/home/:id?param1");
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
    url: urlMatcher 
});
```

The example in plunker:

```
  var sourceList= ['John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo']
  var names = sourceList.join('|');
  var urlMatcher = $urlMatcherFactory.compile("/{source:(?:" + names + ")}/:id");

  $stateProviderRef 
    .state('names', { 
      url: urlMatcher,
      templateUrl: 'tpl.root.html',
      controller: 'MyCtrl'
    });
```

The [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/MdazdvpVKjZhNjI6ErAH?p=preview) is showing a bit more complex solution. If we do have the list of names during cofnig phase... the simple join should work. But if it will be availabel later (`.run()`) via `$http` ... this solution could help

Comment: Thanks....I have list of names during config phase,so i just used join and $urlMatcherFactory and it worked.

Comment: Everything may be done in config phase without injecting `$urlMatcherFactory`. Forked plunk is here http://plnkr.co/edit/gDHagwOlJoftTakv7GwV?p=preview

Comment: Great job @sbedulin, thanks you spend some time to append that updated plunker. Great!

Answer (score 3):

Previous answers are ok, but I most of the time need something simpler solution like this:

```
 url: '/something/{source:(?:' + ['John', 'Paul'].join('|') + ')}/:id',
```

without need for using $urlMatcherFactory