# simple regex route constraints for UI-Router

Tags: regex, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to constrain a route so only `'/route1'` or `'/route2'` resolve to the following rule:

```
$stateProvider.state("promotional", {
    url: "/{contentType}",
    templateUrl: coreConfig.path() + "/modules/content/content.tmpl.html",
    controller: "promotionalController",
    controllerAs: "contentCtrl",
    data: { requiresLogin: true }
});
```

for **`url`** I've tried

```
url: "/{contentType: (route1|route2)}"

url: "/{contentType: [(route1|route2)]}"

url: "/{contentType: [route1|route2]}"
```

and none of these seemed to work.  Any solutions?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will solve it (may be other problems), but I'm very sure that you have to get rid of the space after `contentType:`. Also, the answer here seems to Successfully do something very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25780039/624590

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OkBrqHdyhcnjuGctlAJZ?p=preview)

We can us regexp like this:

```
 // just routes 'route1' or 'route2'
 $stateProvider
    .state("promotional", {
        url: "/{contentType:(?:route1|route2)}",
        templateUrl: coreConfig.path() + "/modules/content/content.tmpl.html",
        controller: "promotionalController",
        controllerAs: "contentCtrl",
        data: { requiresLogin: true }
    })

    // similar but only for 'route3' or 'route4' or 'route5'
    .state("other", {
        url: "/{contentType:(?:route3|route4|route5)}",
        templateUrl: coreConfig.path() + "/modules/content/content.tmpl.html",
        controller: "promotionalController",
        controllerAs: "contentCtrl",
        data: { requiresLogin: true }
    })
```

Similar issues:

- [Matching url with array list of words in AngularJS ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25779203/1679310)
- [AngularJS ui-router - two identical route groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30288859/1679310)

Check the above example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OkBrqHdyhcnjuGctlAJZ?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You can use RegEx with a UrlMatcher, something like this (untested):

```
 var urlMatcher = $urlMatcherFactory.compile("/route[1-2]");

 $stateProvider
 .state("promotional", {
        url: urlMatcher,
        templateUrl: coreConfig.path() + "/modules/content/content.tmpl.html",
        controller: "promotionalController",
        controllerAs: "contentCtrl",
        data: { requiresLogin: true }
 });
```