# Angular UI Router - Dynamic TemplateURL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I am building a static HTML website with angular UI router for navigation. I basically have one ui-view with multiple (10+) html templates (pages) to load into that view. All my template pages are in a directory called 'pages'.

So i basically want to know if we can define just one state in the $stateProvider to assign multiple template urls dynamically instead of writing different states for each HTML template page (like mentioned below).

```
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
    controller: 'homeController',
    controllerAs: 'home'
})
.state('viz', {
    url: '/viz',
    templateUrl: 'pages/viz.html',
    controller: 'vizController',
    controllerAs: 'viz'
})
.state('about', {
    url: '/about',
    templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
    controller: 'aboutController',
    controllerAs: 'about'
})....
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can, but you will be stepping away from the whole point of ui-router. The back button won't work, it isn't as scalable etc. If you want to do it this way you could just use nginclude.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That should not be so difficult, check for example this:

#### [Angular UI-Router dynamic routing based on slug from API Ajax Call. Load view based on slug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30409740/1679310)

We can use `$stateParams` and `templateProvider` to

```
.state('general', {
   url: '/{type}',
   //templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
   templateProvider: ['$stateParams', '$templateRequest',
      function($stateParams, $templateRequest) 
      {
        var tplName = "pages/" + $stateParams.type + ".html";
        return $templateRequest(tplName);
      }
    ],
    // general controller instead of home
    //controller: 'homeController',
    controller: 'generalController',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl'
```

We can also restrict the parameter `type` to be just one of the expected values, see:

```
url: '/{type:(?:home|viz|about)}',
```

#### [Angular js - route-ui add default parmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31459394/1679310)

There is also very similar Q & A with working plunker and more details:

#### [AngularJS ui-router - two identical route groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30288859/1679310)

Another examples could be found here:

- [Trying to Dynamically set a templateUrl in controller based on constant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27774287/1679310)
- [Angular UI-router and using dynamic templates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26864152/1679310)

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Cheers.

Comment: Great to see that, sir ;) Enjoy mighty UI-Router!