# Angular passing parameters through templateUrl in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using `angular` and `sails` to build a web app, in which each user have their own them so to display their public profile I have to use  different templates. I am using `ui-router` and if I can pass id passed to the `route` url to `templateUrl` field I can solve this problem easily, so is there a way to do that ??

```js
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  $stateProvider
    .state('profile', {
      abstract: true,
      url: '',
      templateUrl: domain + "/profile/master",
      controller: 'profileController'
    })
    .state('profile.user', {
      url: '/user/:id',
      templateUrl: domain + '/angular/profile/:id',
      controller: 'privateProfileController'
    });
});
```

Comment: please refer  resolve in uri routing

Comment: resolve: {
               data : function () { return data; }
            }

Comment: Check [Angular UI Router - Dynamic TemplateURL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734690/angular-ui-router-dynamic-templateurl?rq=1)

Comment: ok .. let me look into it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[source link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/163)

```
.state('contacts.detail', {
  url: '/{contactId}',
  views: {
    'menu': {
        templateUrl:
                 function (stateParams){
                    return '/partials/contacts.detail' + stateParams.contactId + '.html';
            }
    }
  }
})
```