# How can I pass a $scope variable as part of component's templateUrl in angularJs 1.5?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angularjs-scope

I have the following code:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

myModule.controller('newController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
                   $scope.id = '1234';
}])
.component('myModalX', {
         templateUrl: `./partials/locationY?id=${$scope.id}`,
         controller: 'newController',
         controllerAs: 'vm'
});
```

This doesn't work. How can I ensure that I can pass `$scope.id` as part of the templateUrl?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular passing parameters through templateUrl in ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34722102/angular-passing-parameters-through-templateurl-in-ui-router)

Comment: No, I'm using Symfony for my routing not ui-router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I figured out how to do it. 
I created a service that has a setter method that accepts the scope I need as a parameter, and a getter method that accesses the set variable in the service.

This way I'm able to access the variable in scope using the getter method in the service.

```
myModule.controller('newController', ['$scope', 'myScopeAcessingService', function($scope, myScopeAcessingService) {
                   $scope.id = '1234';
                   myScopeAcessingService.setValue($scope);

}])
.component('myModalX', {
         templateUrl: function(myScopeAcessingService) {

           const theIdIneed = myScopeAcessingService.getValue();

           return `./partials/locationY?id=${theIdIneed}`
         },
         controller: 'newController',
         controllerAs: 'vm'
});
```