# dynamic change of templateUrl in ui-router from one state to another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

html:

```
<a ui-sref="user.tools.selectedTemplate({provider: t.id})" target="_blank">{{t.name}}</a>
```

Above code is in ng-repeat with many template links loaded with name and id so when i click each link , href will be updated with id number appended to selected template link. I am generating about ten templates with same controller. I am passing value in ui-sref from one state to another so i need dynamic templateUrl,
i tried this [link issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/163) but i cant able to send stateparams since the main template page has no params.

Here the ui router code in app.js

```
.state('user.tools.template',angularAMD.route({
    url: '/template',
    templateUrl: './views/tools/select-template.html',
    controller: 'selectTplCtrl',
    controllerUrl: 'tools/selecttplCtrl'
}))

.state('user.tools.selectedTemplate',angularAMD.route({
    url: '/selectedTemplate/:provider',
    templateUrl: function($stateParams){
        return './views/tools/selected-template'+'$stateParams.provider'+'.html'
    },
    controller: 'selectedTemplateCtrl',
    controllerUrl: 'tools/selectedTemplateCtrl'
}))
```

Can anyone solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that you are on the right track.. just URL construction should be adjusted like this:

```
templateUrl: function($stateParams){
    //return './views/tools/selected-template'+'$stateParams.provider'+'.html'
    return './views/tools/selected-template'+ $stateParams.provider +'.html'
}
```

See more here, what we can have with UI-Router when working with dynamic template link:

- [Angular UI Router - Dynamic TemplateURL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33734690/1679310)
- [Angular UI Router: decide child state template on the basis of parent resolved object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25289135/1679310)
- [Angular and UI-Router, how to set a dynamic templateUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26868796/1679310)

Comment: ah! Thanks @Radim Kohler for answering me. and for extra dynamic solutions :)

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow ;) Enjoy UI-Router, sir