# How to supply the separate `template` when param exist?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I have a scenario, to handle the params. ( when param exist it will handled differently )

so, how can i keep 2 templates and use them according to the requirement? at present I am trying like this, which is not working at all.

any one help me?

my state with 2 template: ( please help me to correct )

```
.state('serialCreateCase', {
    url: '/serialCreateCase?sn=',
    views:{
      "" : {
        "templateUrl": 'app/login/loginWithSerial.html'
      },
      "?sn=" : {
        "templateUrl": 'app/login/login.html'
      }
    }
 })
```

here is the redirection with 2 scenarios: ( correct me if I am wrong )

```
if(!$rootScope.isUserLoggedIn && toParams.sn !== undefined ) {

    console.log('dont take action', toState, toParams.sn );
    $rootScope.canNavigate = true;
    $state.go('serialCreateCase'); //works
    $state.go('serialCreateCase', {sn:'1234'}); //not works
    event.preventDefault();
    return;

 }
```

Comment: use, `$stateParams` instead of `toParams`

Comment: can you give me a sample, I don't have any idea about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/L5mZCH2n4kId9IIQT1mC?p=preview)

I would say that you need replace templateUrl with

> ### [Templates](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#templates)
>
> #### TemplateUrl ...
>
> templateUrl can also be a function that returns a url. It takes one preset parameter, stateParams, which is NOT
>   injected.
>
> #### TemplateProvider
>
> Or you can use a template provider function which can be injected, has access to locals, and must return template HTML,
>   like this...

There are more details and plunkers

- [Angular UI Router: decide child state template on the basis of parent resolved object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25289135/1679310)
- [dynamic change of templateUrl in ui-router from one state to another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38841702/1679310)

This I prefer the most

```
...
templateProvider: [$stateParams, '$templateRequest',
  function($stateParams, templateRequest) 
  {
    var tplName = "pages/" + $stateParams.type + ".html";
    return templateRequest(tplName);
  }
],
```

(check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33734690/1679310)) because it uses also **`$templateRequest`**

#### EXTEND

There is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/L5mZCH2n4kId9IIQT1mC?p=preview)

this could be the state def

```
  .state('serialCreateCase', {
    url: '/serialCreateCase?sn',
    views: {
      "": {
        templateProvider: ['$stateParams', '$templateRequest',
          function($stateParams, templateRequest) {
            var tplName = "app/login/loginWithSerial.html";
            if($stateParams.sn){
               tplName = "app/login/login.html";
            }
            return templateRequest(tplName);
          }
        ]
      },
    }
  });
```

what we really need is to always pass some value, as **`sn`**. So, these should be the calls:

```
  // we need to pass some value, to be sure that there will be other than last
  <a ui-sref="serialCreateCase({sn: null})">
  // here is reasonable value
  <a ui-sref="serialCreateCase({sn:'1234'})">
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/L5mZCH2n4kId9IIQT1mC?p=preview) in action

Comment: Hi Radim, I am trying usiing `templateProvider` with parameter, But it seem not working. `$state.go('serialCreateCase', {sn:toParams.sn}); //not works`

Comment: I created a plunker and extend the answer.. hope it will help a bit ;)

Answer (score 1):

use, `$stateParams` instead of `toParams`,

1) **Deciding the template depending on the param(your requirement)**

```
.state('serialCreateCase', {
        url: '/serialCreateCase?sn=',
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: function(stateParams) {
                    var param = stateParams.sn
                    return (param == undefined) ? 'app/login/loginWithSerial.html' : 'app/login/login.html'
                },
                controller: 'myController',
            }
        }
      })
```

You can check the `stateParam` using the parameter of `templateUrl`, and change the templates.

**2) change the state depending on the param from controller.**

This is a sample controller where you can check the `state parameter` and use the re directions as your wish.

```
allControllers.controller('myController', ['$scope','$rootScope','$state','$stateParams',
    function($scope,$rootScope,$state,$stateParams) {
        if(!$rootScope.isUserLoggedIn)
        {
            if($stateParams.sn !== undefined )  
            {
                alert('dont take action', $stateParams.sn );
            }
            else
            {
                alert('You can redirect, no parameter present');    
            }

        }
    }   
}])
```

Comment: Where do you deciding the template here?

Comment: @3gwebtrain, I have given a sample how to use the state params. if you tell me the exact requirement, I will modify the answer.

Comment: I would like to use 2 templates according to the requirement

Comment: Updated my answer, please check now.

Comment: when I use to like this; `$state.go('serialCreateCase', {sn:toParams.sn}); //not works` - not working what is wrong here?

Comment: as I told you, dont use `toParams`, use  `$stateParams`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126186/discussion-between-3gwebtrain-and-sravan).