# Angular js - route-ui add default parmeter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

In my app I use angular UI-Router.

I have locals (English and Hebrew)
My base language is English.

Thats why i want if the language is English not to add the parameter to the url

For example:

- Home English --> `http://example.com/`
- Home Hebrew --> `http://example.com/he/`
- About us English --> `http://example.com/about`
- About us Hebrew --> `http://example.com/he/about`

Is this possible ?

This is my current code

```
$stateProvider
        .state('/', {
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: "Assets/app/templates/home.html",
            controller: 'homeController'
        })
        .state('activity', {
            url: "/activity",
            templateUrl: "Assets/app/templates/gallery.html",
            controller: 'galleryController'
        })
        .state('page', {
            url: '/:pagename',
            templateUrl: "Assets/app/templates/page.html",
            controller: 'pageController'
        });
```

Answer (score 10):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iQoyofkSCkhJdezXMlyQ?p=preview)

As always, that is feasible with `UI-Router` - built in features. Firstly, we'd introduce the super parent state called for example 'root'. It would have defined parameter **`lang`**

```
.state('root', {
    url: '/{lang:(?:en|he|cs)}',
    abstract: true,
    template: '<div ui-view=""></div>',
    params: {lang : { squash : true, value: 'en' }}
})
```

Interesting things to mention: The **`url`** uses regexp to reduce amount of matching lang words *(in our case, English, Hebrew and Czech)* :

```
url: '/{lang:(?:en|he|cs)}',
```

Read [more e.g. here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25779203/1679310).

Also, we do profit from a setting called **`params : {}`**. It says, that the default value is **`'en'`** and what is more important - it should be squashed, skipped if there is a match with 'en' param value:

```
params: {lang : { squash : true, value: 'en' }}
```

Read [more e.g. here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25647714/1679310) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30230421/1679310)

So, this is our parent, root state, which we just would apply to all states with a state definition setting **`parent : 'root'`**:

```
.state('home', {
    parent: 'root', // parent will do the magic
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: "Assets/app/templates/home.html",
    controller: 'homeController'
})
.state('activity', {
    parent: 'root', // parent magic
    url: "/activity",
    templateUrl: "Assets/app/templates/gallery.html",
    controller: 'galleryController'
})
.state('page', {
    parent: 'root', // magic
    url: '/page/:pagename',
    templateUrl: "Assets/app/templates/page.html",
    controller: 'pageController'
});
```

And now these links would work:

**ui-sref** English:

```
<a ui-sref="home({lang: 'en'})">home({lang: 'en'})</a>
<a ui-sref="activity({lang: 'en'})">activity({lang: 'en'})</a>
<a ui-sref="page({pagename:'one', lang: 'en'})">page({pagename:'one', lang: 'en'})</a>
```

**ui-sref** Hebrew:

```
<a ui-sref="home({lang: 'he'})">home({lang: 'he'})</a>
<a ui-sref="activity({lang: 'he'})">activity({lang: 'he'})</a>
<a ui-sref="page({pagename:'two', lang: 'he'})">page({pagename:'two'})</a>
```

**href** English:

```
<a href="#/">#/</a>
<a href="#/activity">#/activity</a>
<a href="#/page/three">#/page/three</a>
```

**href** Hebrew:

```
<a href="#/he/">#/he/</a>
<a href="#/he/activity">#/he/activity</a>
<a href="#/he/page/three">#/he/page/three</a>
```

Check it [in action here](http://plnkr.co/edit/iQoyofkSCkhJdezXMlyQ?p=preview)