# AngularJS UI-Router optional url segment in the middle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I want to have an optional url segment for the following example:

```
url: "/post/:category/:subcategory/:title/{id:int}",
```

In the above example subcategory is optional. For example it will accept:

```
url: "/post/sports/football/some-title/10",
```

and it will also accept:

```
url: "/post/sports/some-title/15",
```

which do not have subcategory. I can do that using to separate states but is there any rule for that?
Please note only subcategory segment is optional. Others are mandatory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.state('post', {
    url: '/post/:category/:subcategory/:title/:{id:int}',
    templateUrl: 'views/post.html',
    controller: 'postCtrl',
    params: {
        subcategory: { squash: true, value: null },
    }
})`

For more info [read the doc](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider)

Answer (score 2):

Solution is in detail described here

#### [Angular js - route-ui add default parmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31459394/1679310)

and here is how we can define such parameter:

```
.state('state', {
    url: '/:category/{subcategory:(?:football|tennis|hokey)}/:title/:id',
    abstract: true,
    template: '<div ui-view=""></div>',
    params: {subcategory : { squash : true, value: 'football' }}
})
```

Comment: Can you explain this part `(?:football|tennis|hokey)` ? Actually subcategory can be a long list.

Comment: that is the regular expression, the set of subcategory known values. That will help UI-Router to understand, if in this part `/post/sports/some-title/` is *some-title* subcategory or just another parameter... Other words, without that (it is really essential part) UI-Router could hardly decide... if it is subcategory or not. So we would need something like that ;)

Comment: Okay, actually I don't care other values except id. Anyways, thanks for your reply.

Comment: yes I understand your point, but as I said subcategory can be a large list and may be dynamically added to database.