# How can i access ui-router's UrlMatcher?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, pattern-matching

In the documentation of `ui-router`there is a object named [UrlMatcher](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.type:UrlMatcher) which i need to access it in order to use some methods (such as `exec`) but i cannot find any clear instructions on how to do it. However that object is described on the documentation page.

I want to be able to do something like:

```
new UrlMatcher('/user/{id}?q&r').exec('/user/bob', {
  x: '1', q: 'hello'
});
```

How can i access that object?

[urlMatcherFactory.js on Github](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/1e46c8d/src/urlMatcherFactory.js#L68)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular has [$urlMatcherFactory and UrlMatchers](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#urlmatcherfactory-and-urlmatchers).

**Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/MdazdvpVKjZhNjI6ErAH?p=preview

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).run(['$urlMatcherFactory',
    function($urlMatcherFactory) {

      var sourceList= ['John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo']
      var names = sourceList.join('|');
      var urlMatcher = $urlMatcherFactory.compile("/{source:(?:" + names + ")}/:id");

      $stateProviderRef 
        .state('names', { 
          url: urlMatcher,
          templateUrl: 'tpl.root.html',
          controller: 'MyCtrl'
        });
    }
  ]);
```

**Refer:** [Discussion on ui-router's UrlMatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25779203/matching-url-with-array-list-of-words-in-angularjs-ui-router).

**Using exec:**

**URL:**/home/1?param1=tt

```
 var urlMatcher = $urlMatcherFactory.compile("/home/:id?param1");
    var matched = urlMatcher.exec($location.path(), $location.search());
```

you get  2 `fields`: **id ==> 1** and **param1 ==> tt**

Comment: I have seen this post but it does not access directly the `UrlMatcher` object

Comment: apparantly, var urlMatcher = $urlMatcherFactory.compile("'/user/{id}?q&r'");
var matched = urlMatcher.exec('/user/bob', {
  x: '1', q: 'hello'
});  Is  this what you meant?

Comment: Yes i'm going to try it.